# Case is not creating in salesforce using email to case functionality from user with @sfr.fr e-mail addresses

Tags: community, salesforce-id, email2case

when user send email to salesforce using email to case functionality it should create new case. But for certain usres its not creating case in salesforce. For example When user send mail to xyz@test.com (Email to case setup is configured for this address) email address from there @sfr.fr e-mail addresses not coming to salesforce. But the user was able to create case long back. Is there any restriction is there here for email address ? Can you please tell me why case is not creating when  email coming from this email address  ?

Comment: Is this some users are not getting cases created when an email comes in? To let the community help you it is best to read the section on how to ask a question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: when user send email to salesforce using email to case functionality it should create new case. But for certain usres its not creating case in salesforce. For example When user send mail to xyz@test.com (Email to case setup is configured for this address) email address from there @sfr.fr e-mail addresses not coming to salesforce. But the user was able to create case long back. Is there any restriction is there here for email address ? Can you please tell me why case is not creating when  email coming from this email address  ?

Comment: so you are saying that email originating from `@sfr.fr` does not create a Case when sent to your email2Case address `xyz@test.com`? Have you checked your mail server to see if it has an exclusion rule or spam filter dealing with mail coming from `@sfr.fr`?